# How to identify a user with auth0 jwt

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, jwt, auth0

I have an angular2 frontend which is using Auth0 for authentication and a .net core app on the backend. All is working with enforcing secured API calls.

**What is the best way to identify an authenticated user on the backend?** A rather clumsy way I can think of doing this is to expose a 'setUserToken' api call which allows me to connect a user ID to either of the following:

- token `var bearerToken = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString()`
- social ID `var socialId = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier").First().Value`

That way, with subsequent API calls, I can simply `findUserByToken()` or `findUserBySocialProviderOpenId()`

I'm sure I'm missing a much more obvious solution to this problem. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sub` claim of the JWT is always generated by Auth0 and will contain the user's identifier, independent of the identity provider that was used to log in.

https://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#rfc.section.4.1.2

> The sub (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the subject of the JWT. The claims in a JWT are normally statements about the subject. The subject value MUST either be scoped to be locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique. The processing of this claim is generally application specific. The sub value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value. Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

In most cases, your backend API should only be a consumer of Auth0 access tokens and not need to expose any endpoints related to authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rodrigo :) My sub claim does, in fact, tell me the identity provider. So (in above example) ```socialId == google-oauth2|[idNumber]```
Although, my main question was how to identify users within my API.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - the `sub` claim is received by your API, so it lets you identify who the user is. Or were you asking a more implementation-specific question?

Comment: That's precisely what I'm looking for :) So in my case the sub claim is the google id. Would you just store the sub claim in the DB against the specific user? I've recently come from a Java EE background so I'm not 100% if .NET has some clever alternative that I'm missing.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to store an ID or have a database at all since JWT allows stateless authentication (you can trust whatever comes in the token). If you do need to store more information about the user in a database, then yes, you would use the `sub` claim as the user's unique ID.

Comment: Ok awesome. That pretty much wraps things up. Thanks for your time.